# Git push local change to remote force failed

Tags: git

I used the following command

```
$ git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
        'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Qt_Creator_Tutorial.pptx' \
        --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all"
```

to remove the file history successfully, but when I used cmd `git push origin --force --all` to push to remote repository, it failed and show below error message:

```
Counting objects: 23, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 1.41 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (7/7)
remote: Processing changes: done
To ssh://zhongle@192.168.2.11:29418/CM_doc
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://zhongle@192.168.2.11:29418/CM_doc'
```

I have set `git config receive.denyNonFastForwards false`, but it still failed, anyone got any suggestion？

Thanks,
Leo

Comment: I believe the order of your `git` command is incorrect. Try the following `git push --force --all`

Comment: Are you sure your remote allows force push?

Comment: Thanks, Felix_Sim, I have tried your suggestion ‘git push --force --all’, but still failed, I have found a way, to do the git filter-branch... directly on the remote repository will solve the issue, it should be OK after my some basic test.